# JMeter JDBC Request with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows, jdbc, jmeter

I cannot get JMeter JDBC Request working with SQL Server.

I've prepared a simplest example, following [this article](https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/database-performance-and-load-testing-using-jmeter-ms-sql-470045303785):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.2.1">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <JDBCDataSource guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JDBCDataSource" testname="JDBC Connection Configuration" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="autocommit">true</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="checkQuery"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="connectionAge">5000</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="connectionProperties">trustServerCertificate=false;</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="dataSource">test_pool</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="dbUrl">jdbc:sqlserver://ssss:1433;database=tempdb;</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="driver">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="initQuery"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="keepAlive">true</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="password">pppp</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="poolMax">0</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="preinit">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="timeout">10000</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="transactionIsolation">DEFAULT</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="trimInterval">60000</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="username">uuuu</stringProp>
      </JDBCDataSource>
      <hashTree/>
      <SetupThreadGroup guiclass="SetupThreadGroupGui" testclass="SetupThreadGroup" testname="setUp Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </SetupThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <JDBCPreProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JDBCPreProcessor" testname="JDBC PreProcessor" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="dataSource">test_pool</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryType">Select Statement</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="query">select @@servername ServerName, DB_NAME() DataBaseName
</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryArguments"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryArgumentsTypes"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="variableNames">ServerName, DataBaseName</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="resultVariable"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryTimeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="resultSetMaxRows"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="resultSetHandler">Store as String</stringProp>
        </JDBCPreProcessor>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="Debug Sampler" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
        </DebugSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <JDBCSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JDBCSampler" testname="JDBC Request" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="dataSource">test_pool</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryType">Select Statement</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="query">select @@servername ServerName, DB_NAME() DataBaseName</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryArguments"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryArgumentsTypes"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="variableNames">ServerName2, DataBaseName2</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="resultVariable"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryTimeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="resultSetMaxRows"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="resultSetHandler">Store as String</stringProp>
        </JDBCSampler>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
            <time>true</time>
            <latency>true</latency>
            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
            <success>true</success>
            <label>true</label>
            <code>true</code>
            <message>true</message>
            <threadName>true</threadName>
            <dataType>true</dataType>
            <encoding>false</encoding>
            <assertions>true</assertions>
            <subresults>true</subresults>
            <responseData>false</responseData>
            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
            <xml>false</xml>
            <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            <bytes>true</bytes>
            <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
            <url>true</url>
            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
            <idleTime>true</idleTime>
            <connectTime>true</connectTime>
          </value>
        </objProp>
        <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
      </ResultCollector>
      <hashTree/>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

The problems are,

- The SQL in `JDBC PreProcessor` works, but I saw no JMeter variable created by it, in the `Debug Sampler` output.
- The SQL in `JDBC Request` step however does not work. It gave the error of

`Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'`

which is very odd, as the JDBC driver & SQL in `JDBC PreProcessor` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your PreProcessor doesn't work at all because it cannot run without a [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) so it's simply **ignored**, you can add i.e. a [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide/) to your setUp Thread Group and this will trigger the JDBC PreProcessor execution
2. The `Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'` error means that you don't have MSSQL [JDBC Driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

So you need to:

1. Download [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and extract `mssql-jdbc-x.x.x.jrex.jar` file to the "lib" folder of your JMeter installation. JMeter restart will be required to pick up the .jar
2. Use `select 1` as the Validation Query in the JDBC Connection Configuration